# Where do I insert my API key in an API GET request?

Tags: r, json, api, get, httr

I am trying to connect to an API endpoint but am having trouble figuring out where to input my API key. I receive an error that tells me that my API key is missing when I have attempted to add it to the GET request. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
url = "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/predictions/1574778f3"


result = GET(url, add_headers('Authorization' = paste("Auhtorization: ", key)))
content(result)
```

There error I receive is as follows: 
$message
[1] "Missing RapidAPI application key. Go to https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/keys to learn how to get your API application key."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you posted seems to state that RapidAPI is looking for a header named "X-RapidAPI-Key" for their API key. Have you tried that instead of using an authorization header? Also, you have Authorization spelled incorrectly in the paste method call which could be part of your issue.

Comment: sorry, I fixed the spelling and receive the same error. Where should i insert the "X-RapidAPI-Key" header?

Comment: I got it.this worked. key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
url = "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/predictions/1574778f3"


result = GET(url, add_headers("X-RapidAPI-Key" = key))
content(result)

Comment: Yeaaah, the same here. I was using "Authorization: Basic xxxx" instead of erase it and put "X-RapidAPI-Key: xxxx". It worked on Fiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$subscription_key  ='xxxxxxxxxxxx';
$url = "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/predictions/1574778f3"
$request_headers = array(
                    "X-RapidAPI-Key:" . $subscription_key
                );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);

    $season_data = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
        exit();
    }

    // Show me the result
    curl_close($ch);
    $json= json_decode($season_data, true);
```